# React Modals all show up at once on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React newbie. I have seen the previous SO suggestions, but they don't help me in the pattern that I have followed here.
Please can anyone tell me how I determine that the clicked button only fires the corresponding modal in this code?
I would like some help with this code effort, as it's taken a while to cobble it together and I understand *some* of what is going on here. Experienced coders will see my *baby steps* here. Thanks.

`This is the returned json`

```
{
    "cakes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Fruit Sponge Layer Cake",
            "comment": "Real fruit - strawberries, Victoria Sponge and cream",
            "image": "./assets/fruitLayerSponge.jpg",
            "alt": "Fruit Sponge",
            "yum": 1,
            "name": "fruitSponge"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Chocolate Muffin",
            "comment": "Chocolate mix, chocco chips and cream",
            "image": "./assets/chocoMuffinsWCream.jpg",
            "alt": "Chocco Muffin",
            "yum": 3,
            "name": "choccoMuffin"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Strawberry Cheesecake",
            "comment": "Cheesecake with strawberry cream",
            "image": "./assets/strawberryCheesecake.jpg",
            "alt": "Cheesecake",
            "yum": 2,
            "name": "cheesecakeStrawberry"

        }
    ]
}
```

`This is the React Component - AsyncAwaitLocalhost.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css"
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class AsyncAwaitLocalhost extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            jsonContent: [],
            greeting: "string",
            newGreeting: "Hello",
            isOpen: false
        };
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        // GET request using fetch with async/await
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/cakes');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ jsonContent: data.cakes, greeting: this.state.greeting, newGreeting: this.state.newGreeting })

    }

    openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });

    closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

    render() {
        const { jsonContent } = this.state;
        const { greeting } = this.state;
        const { newGreeting } = this.state;
        this.state.greeting = "Hello greeting";
        this.state.newGreeting = "Hi new greeting";
        console.log("greeting: " + greeting);
        console.log("newGreeting: " + newGreeting);

        // the inline JSX render component definition
        const Cake = ({ name, id, text, image, comment, dbutton, dmodal }) => (
            <div>
                <img src={image} width="120px" alt={name}/>
                <div>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    <p>{comment}</p>
                    <p>{id}</p>
                    <div>{dbutton}</div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <div id="dModal" className="dModalClosed">{dmodal}</div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return (

            <div className="card text-center m-3">
                <h5 className="card-header">See Cakes</h5>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div>
                        {this.state.jsonContent.map((cake, index) => (
                            <Cake
                                name={`${cake.id} ${cake.name}`}
                                image={cake.image}
                                text={cake.text}
                                comment={cake.comment}
                                key={index}
                                dbutton={<Button onClick={this.openModal}>See more {cake.id}</Button>}
                                dmodal={
                                    <Modal id={cake.name} show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
                                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                            <Modal.Title>{cake.text}</Modal.Title>
                                        </Modal.Header>
                                        <Modal.Body>name={`${cake.id} ${cake.name}`}
                                            image={cake.image}
                                            text={cake.text}
                                            comment={cake.comment}
                                        </Modal.Body>
                                        <Modal.Footer>
                                            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                                                Close
                                            </Button>
                                        </Modal.Footer>
                                    </Modal>
                                }
                            />
                        ))}
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { AsyncAwaitLocalhost };
```

Comment: You're currently using the same single `isOpen` state for all modals. You'll need to track an "is open" state for each individual modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a boolean to control open for all Modal. You need to using id/index to control this:

```
this.state = {
  isOpen: null
};
...
onClick={this.openModal(index)}
...
openModal = (index) => () => this.setState({ isOpen: index });
closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: null });
...
show={this.state.isOpen === index}
```

Comment: Thanks @Viet. Implementing your solution took a minute, or two and solved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

These lines both change `isOpen` on the state of your `AsyncAwaitLocalhost`.

```js
openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });

closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });
```

All your modals are set to display when `this.state.isOpen` is true:

```js
<Modal id={cake.name} show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
```

So, whenever you set `this.state.isOpen` to true on your `AsyncAwaitLocalhost`, as happens whenever you call `openModal()`, all of the modals will show.

You should either break the modals out into their own components and store this in the state of the individual modals, or store an ID somewhere telling your code which modal to open.